# How to download .xlsm ,docx, png,jpg files using python from a http GET request

Tags: python, http-headers, response-headers

I am downloading content from a link using python GET request, there are certain content type headers which i am not able to save. The file types of pdf,csv,jpeg,xlsx are getting saved fine when i write the corressponding contents to the file types, but the jpg,png,xlsxm,docx contents not getting saved, though the content type headers for these file types, are correct and as received from the response.

Please let me know how to save these file types

```
if(contentType1 == 'application/pdf;charset=UTF-8'):
        pod_file = open('downloads/POD_'+str(el)+".pdf",'wb')
        pod_file.write(response1.content)
        pod_file.close()
      elif(contentType1 == 'image/jpeg;charset=UTF-8'):
        pod_file = open('downloads/POD_'+str(el)+".jpeg",'wb')
        pod_file.write(response1.content)
        pod_file.close()
      elif(contentType1 == 'image/jpg;charset=UTF-8'):
        pod_file = open('downloads/POD_'+str(el)+".jpg",'wb')
        pod_file.write(response1.content)
        pod_file.close()
      elif(contentType1 == 'image/png;charset=UTF-8'):
        pod_file = open('downloads/POD_'+str(el)+".png",'wb')
        pod_file.write(response1.content)
        pod_file.close()
      elif(contentType1 == 'image/tiff;charset=UTF-8'):
        pod_file = open('downloads/POD_'+str(el)+".tiff",'wb')
        pod_file.write(response1.content)
        pod_file.close()
      elif(contentType1 == 'image/jfif;charset=UTF-8'):
        pod_file = open('downloads/POD_'+str(el)+".jfif",'wb')
        pod_file.write(response1.content)
        pod_file.close()
      elif(contentType1 == 'application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8'):
        pod_file = open('downloads/POD_'+str(el)+".xls",'wb')
        pod_file.write(response1.content)
        pod_file.close()
      elif(contentType1 == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8'):
        pod_file = open('downloads/POD_'+str(el)+".xlsx",'wb')
        pod_file.write(response1.content)
        pod_file.close()
      elif(contentType1 == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;charset=UTF-8'):
        pod_file = open('downloads/POD_'+str(el)+".docx",'wb')
        pod_file.write(response1.content)
        pod_file.close()
      elif(contentType1 == 'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12;charset=UTF-8'):
        pod_file = open('downloads/POD_'+str(el)+".xlsm",'wb')
        pod_file.write(response1.content)
        pod_file.close()
      elif(contentType1 == 'text/csv;charset=UTF-8'):
        pod_file = open('downloads/POD_'+str(el)+".csv",'wb')
        pod_file.write(response1.content)
        pod_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

#### FOR DOC File (you can use different thing for download different type of File or USE same code)

```
def save_link(book_link, book_name):
    the_book = requests.get(book_link, stream=True)
    with open(book_name, 'wb') as f:
      for chunk in the_book.iter_content(1024 * 1024 * 2):  # 2 MB chunks
        f.write(chunk)

save_link("URL","NAME.docx")
```

#### FOR IMAGE

```
import shutil

url = 'http://example.com/img.png'
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open('img.png', 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , testing it out for the different file types with the above mentioned code snippets. will update you.

Comment: The png files are downloading fine, but the .docx contents though saved, the file doesn't open giving 'unreadable content. ..." message.

Comment: is your Docx contains image of more than 19?
Because If we add 20 times the same image (or 20 unique images) document got an error when we trying to open it: "Word found unreadable content..."
However if we do the same things but 19 times, it got no issues.

Comment: You can refer to this https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/455

Comment: Thanks , there are lots of images and tables in the content which i am writing to the  .docx file, using the python-docx now in trying to solve it.

Comment: Able to download docx, xlsm, xlsx, tiff and other files the response content type received from http request had to be identified correctly.